# WEBrick errors on ruby 1.8, works fine on ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, webrick

I have the following script which runs a web server and executes a command when a request is received.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'webrick'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(port: ARGV.first)
server.mount_proc '/' do |req, res|
  r10kstatus = system( "sudo r10k deploy environment -pv warn" )
  puts r10kstatus
end

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

Unfortunatly, I need to backport this to work on ruby 1.8 (since scripting rvm to work on distributed systems is a pain).

When I try and run the script on ruby 1.8, I get the following error:

`` /usr/bin/r10k_gitlab_webhook:19:in `load': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/r10k_gitlab_webhook-0.1.0/bin/r10k_gitlab_webhook:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(Port: ARGV.first)
                                      ^
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/r10k_gitlab_webhook-0.1.0/bin/r10k_gitlab_webhook:4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
    from /usr/bin/r10k_gitlab_webhook:19 ``

How could this script be modified to work on ruby 1.8?

**Update**

I've changed 'Port' to 'port'

**Update2**

Comparing the ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9 documentation for webrick, shows that there isn't a port parameter for the new method in 1.8

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServer.html#method-c-new

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServer.html#method-c-new

I've tried changing `(Port: ARGV.first)` to `(port: ARGV.first)`, yet it still gives the same error:

`server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(port: ARGV.first)
                                      ^
r10k_gitlab_webhook_old.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end`

Comment: `Port: ARGV.first` should be `port: ARGV.first`

Comment: changed `Port` to `port` should avoid `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'`. The problem persists?

Comment: `do ... end` cannot happen on one line. The single-line syntax is `{ ... }`

Comment: `Port: ARGV.first` is using ruby 1.9 hash syntax, in 1.8, you need to use the classic hash rocket syntax: `:Port => ARGV.first`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key: value` syntax for hashes (where `key` is a symbol) was introduced in Ruby 1.9. For Ruby 1.8 you need to use the `:key => value` syntax:

```
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => ARGV.first)
```

(and I think it is `:Port`).

Comment: That's actually how it works, isn't it? Completely non-standard option names. WebBrick isn't very Ruby and it's kind of shocking it's still bundled. That thing is so shamefully out of date.

Comment: Thank you so much! With your change it now works on ruby 1.8 and ruby 2.0. (And yes, it is 'Port', not 'port')